# How to use setInterval to update data and give it to react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my function in AppHelper.js file

```
getTimeCountDown: function() {
  //some code...
  return  minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

And in my react component

```
<div>{AppHelper.getTimeCountDown()}</div>
```

and it will show like 23:00 on screen.

What I want to do, is call this function every 1 minutes, how can I do that?Can I use setInterval? where to use?

Comment: In componentDidMount you should start you interval and update component's state, then just render it. don't forget to clear interval at unmount

Answer (score 5):

Think this is most wise decision:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({time: AppHelper.getTimeCountDown()})
    }, 1000 * 60)
}
componentWillUnmount(){
   clearInterval(this.interval);
}
render() {
    return <div>{this.state.time}</div>
}
```

Comment: This will update every 1000 milliseconds, not every minute. Otherwise, looks good!

Comment: `componentDidMount` does not receive any arguments